# Gradient of a quadratic form

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R$ a differentiable function, such that  $f(x)=x\cdot (Ax)$ where $A = [a_{ij}] \in Mat_{dxd}(\mathbb R)$ is a simetric matrix.

I want to prove that $\nabla f(x)= 2Ax$, to do that I used the formula $$(f\cdot g)'_v(x)= f'_v(x)\cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot g'_v(x)$$ to get $$f'_v(x)=v\cdot (Ax) + x\cdot (Av)$$
is this suppose to be equal to $v\cdot (2Ax)$? How do I justify that?

Comment: One way is to write out in coordinates $f(x_1,\dots,x_d) = \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq d} a_{ij}\; x_i\, x_j$

Comment: Caution: $f(x)=x^TAx$. This makes a whole difference.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's just different notation but it means the same.

Comment: You are not obliged to believe me.

Comment: You haven’t used the symmetry of $A$ yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use the fact that $A$ is simmetric!

$$x\cdot (Av)= x^TAv=x^TA^Tv=(Ax)^Tv$$

therefore $$f'(v)=v\cdot (2Ax) = v\cdot \nabla f(x) \forall v \in \mathbb R^d$$

$$\iff 2Ax=\nabla f(x)$$